# How to get names and values of method's parameters?

Tags: kotlin

Is there possibility to get names of method's parameters inside method code? Can anyone show example of it?

I found only this solution at this time, but dislike it..:

```
class Greeter() {

    fun greet(name: String) {
        val c = Greeter::class;
        for (m in c.memberFunctions) {
            if (m.name == "greet") {
                val p = m.parameters
                println(p.toString())
            }
        }
        println("Hello, ${name}");
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Greeter().greet("UserName")
}
```

update: i found another solution, but now i have one more question:
How to get pairs of ParamName, ParamValue at function greet?

```
class Greeter() {

    fun greet(name: String) {
        val p = Greeter::greet.parameters
        println(p.toString())
        println("Hello, ${name}");
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Greeter().greet("UserName")
}
```

Comment: What is your use case for obtaining parameter values reflectively?

Comment: @alexander-udalov I'm new to Java/Kotlin.. Just want to write wrapper over MyBatis: to refactor this lines of code: 
    `fun run_sql(param1, param2) { sql_params.put("param1", param1);
    sql_params.put("param2", param2); }` to loop over parameters list

Comment: In that case I think using a class where all those values are listed as properties, and passing an instance of that class would suit you better

Answer (score 9):

Parameter names are available through the [`KParameter.name`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-parameter/name.html) property:

```
class Greeter() {
    fun greet(name: String) {
        val p = Greeter::greet.parameters
        println("Hello, ${p[0].name}")
    }
}
```

Parameter *values*, on the other hand, cannot be obtained reflectively easily on JVM.